# How to hurry a wonder as China with a builder

Tags: civilization-6

I'm playing as China and I'm supposed to be able to hurry up a wonder with a builder. I've positioned my brand new builder in the city as well as the tile where the wonder is being build and I can't seem to find out in game or goggling how to hurry it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The builder needs to be in the tile where the wonder is being built.  They will then have an option to help build the wonder, similarly to building other tile improvements.  Note that it only works on Ancient and Classical wonders, so if it isn't working, you might be working on a more modern wonder that isn't eligible.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that it only works on really wonders.

Comment: What are "really winders"? Did you mean "really old ..."?

Comment: Sorry, missed that comment. Yeah, auto correct ate my "early" :)